# lib/python3.5/site-packages/charset_normalizer/api.py, line 71 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, debian, python-2.x

Есть нужда запустить скрипт python на Debian 7.7 . Установлен python 3.5.2 (после 3.4.2 по этой [инструкции](https://docs.linuxconsulting.mn.it/notes/install-python-3.4-and-mysql-connector-on-debian-7-wheezy) и дефолтного 2.7) При попытке запуска скрипта вываливается ошибка синтаксиса:

```
{ 
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels# python --version
Python 3.5.2
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels# python connect.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 6, in <module>
    from main import get_wheels
  File "/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels/virtualenv-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from charset_normalizer import __version__ as charset_normalizer_version
  File "/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels/virtualenv-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/charset_normalizer/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .api import from_bytes, from_fp, from_path, normalize
  File "/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels/virtualenv-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/charset_normalizer/api.py", line 71
    previous_logger_level: int = logger.level
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels# cd ..
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin# update-alternatives --config python
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin# python --version
Python 3.5.2
}
```

Попытки апдейта и апгрейда не влияют на результат.

```
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels# apt-get update | grep '404' | wc -l
.....
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
4
(virtualenv-3.5) root@(none):/usr/local/bin/tyres_wheels# apt-get upgrade | grep '404' | wc -l
....
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/r/rpcbind/rpcbind_0.2.0-8+deb7u2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.2.132 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
156
```

Использование `--fix-missing` не влияет на ситуацию.

Есть тестовая виртуалка на vagrant (libvirt) Ububntu 14.04 (*не удалось найти бокс в дебиан 7*),
там с python 3.4.3 запускается скрипт и отрабатывает.

На этой машине python 3.4 падал с ошибкой синтаксиса при попытке обновления pip

```
python3.4: Error while finding spec for 'pip.__main__' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'typing');
```

Подобная проблема обсуждалась [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042780/getting-error-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-when-run-the-code) - но решения нет.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Установил Python 3.6  и проблема решилась